# Bluetooth not working on Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth

I have never had much luck with Ubuntu and bluetooth, things have not changed (for me at least) with 16.04. (Xubuntu 16.04). Thought I would post a question at last.

I have googled the life out of this, too many links to mention, and I am unable to get bluetooth working correctly. I have managed to pair my phone, have broken the pair, removed and re-installed packages, tried command line tools (bluetoothctl for example) and tried the bluez GUI.

All I want to do is send files between PC and phone, all I have managed to do is connect the phone as an audio source (although I have somehow broken that again).

So the short question is this. Is bluetooth just broken in Ubuntu (Xubuntu) ? If not, can anybody link me to a guide on how to set it up ? I guess I am asking more specifically if bluetooth is broken using XFCE.

Please, no obstract links to the Arch wiki or such. I have spent many a long hour into the wee hours reading page after page of Arch wiki/Ask Ubuntu/Open suse/howtogeek/Linux mint etc etc etc forums. While they are very informative and a thouroughly good read, I just want to know if I can get bluetooth working with a few mouse clicks.

It's 2016, bluetooth should just work !

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10f0] (rev 05)
    DeviceName: Intel(R) 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation 82578DC Gigabit Network Connection [8086:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0c45:62f0 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1784:0001 TopSeed Technology Corp. eHome Infrared Transceiver
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 04e8:6865 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III] (PTP mode)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c312 Logitech, Inc. DeLuxe 250 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Many thanks for reading my rant and for any advice offered.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command. It depends on what BT hardware you have. XFCE is not related at all.

Comment: You could look into using KDE Connect.  It uses Wifi, but a very secured connection.  Easy to file transfer.  It does require an app for your android phone.  https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect

Comment: I have used KDE connect, works well. However, I just want to get bluetooth working because Im often without wifi.

Comment: Ah, good point.  I couldn't get my Bluetooth working that well, so that is why I went to KDE Connect or I just use USB for connection to it.  I have been using Xubuntu for quite sometime now.  Maybe someone will answer you with a good stable answer that will work.  =)